# import Charts conflicts with cocoa pod library's name

Tags: xcode, import, ios-charts, swiftui-charts

I am trying to use Apple's Swift Charts (iOS 16 only) but it can't compile, I presume because the import statement is interpreted as targeting this library: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts (that I am using in other places in the App and installed via Cocoapods) and not Apple's Swift Charts as I want to.

Using Swift Chart's API results in compile error: "Can not find 'Chart' in scope"

**Any fix, workaround or better way to specify better what to import is welcomed**, haven't found any other solution than nuking this library from my project, however I would need it for users with iOS 15 or less.

I seem to be unable to use Swift Charts because of this library